# What's causing automation error/unspecified error 2147467259 (80004005) in my macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched for an answer to this but i cant find anything i can make sense of as i'm a bit of a noob and was looking for a layman's explanation.

The macro is to push some data through to access when you click submit.

So far as i can tell it might be something to do with ActiveX Data Objects references but to be honest this is my first project of this type and i could really use some help.

This is my code:

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
    ' connect to the Access database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=M:\DataBase2.mdb;"
    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "ShiftSwapData", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
    ' all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("Date Submitted").Value = Trim(Cells(50, 1).Text)
            .Fields("Agent Email").Value = Trim(Cells(50, 2).Text)
            .Fields("Date Requested").Value = Trim(Cells(50, 3).Text)
            .Fields("Payback Date 1").Value = Trim(Cells(50, 4).Text)
            .Fields("Payback Date 2").Value = Trim(Cells(50, 5).Text)
            .Fields("Shift Start").Value = Trim(Cells(50, 6).Text)
            .Fields("Shift End").Value = Trim(Cells(50, 7).Text)
            .Fields("RDO").Value = Trim(Cells(50, 8).Text)
            .Fields("Call Type").Value = Trim(Cells(50, 9).Text)
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the error is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing your `With...End With` block like this:

```
Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("Date Submitted").Value = Trim(Cells(r, 1).Text)
        .Fields("Agent Email").Value = Trim(Cells(r, 2).Text)
        .Fields("Date Requested").Value = Trim(Cells(r, 3).Text)
        .Fields("Payback Date 1").Value = Trim(Cells(r, 4).Text)
        .Fields("Payback Date 2").Value = Trim(Cells(r, 5).Text)
        .Fields("Shift Start").Value = Trim(Cells(r, 6).Text)
        .Fields("Shift End").Value = Trim(Cells(r, 7).Text)
        .Fields("RDO").Value = Trim(Cells(r, 8).Text)
        .Fields("Call Type").Value = Trim(Cells(r, 9).Text)
        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
    End With
loop
```

now when it tries to do the `.Update` it won't find a duplicate row.

The **Cells** object is used like this:

**Cells** *(Row,Column)*

HTH
Philip

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0
```

, is looking strange for me, because to me its a whole column, so asking for a formula for an entire column is odd

maybe change the range part to

```
len(cells(1,r).formula)>0
```

or

```
range("A" & trim(str(r))).formula if you mean A3, A4, ...
```